# Does CKEditor work properly in prototype.js enabled environment?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, textarea, ckeditor

With prototype.js on a page no popup works for CKEditor, i.e the smiley popup, image popup window etc. I get the following error from IE when I click on any button with a popup and then everything freezes on the page:

**prototype.js, line 460 character 5
SCRIPT5030: Array length must be assigned a finite positive number**

Then in firebug this error apperars: **invalid array length**, when the following tries to run from prototype:

```
shift: function() {  
    var result = this[0];  
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++)  
    this[i] = this[i + 1];  
    this.length--;  
    return result;  
},
```

What can I do to have CKEditor  work along with prototype?

Comment: does ckeditor define a shift function as well? does one overwrite the other? the old version of (f)ckeditor works with jquery..dunno bout prototype.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor doesn't touch any of the native objects/prototypes, but Prototype.JS unfortunately does this and AFAIK there were problems (in versions <1.6) with their implementations that weren't compliant with native ones. So there's a possibility that old version of Prototype.JS overwrites some native thing which we're using.

So which versions of Prototype.JS and CKEditor are you using? I've just tested CKEditor's trunk version with Prototype.JS 1.7.1 and everything works fine.

Comment: Although this question is over a year old, he might be talking about things like this: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8940 you know, there are lots of reported bugs with patches that are waiting idle in the dev site.

Comment: Oups. I don't know where I've found this question :D

Answer (score 0):

i just had same problem and downloading latest version of both prototype.js and ckeditor/ckfinder worked fine.